# Generate swagger Open 'file': permission denied

Tags: docker, go, swagger, go-swagger

I tried to generate swagger using this command
`swagger generate spec -o ./swagger.yaml --scan-models`

but I got error like this :

> open ./swagger.yaml: permission denied

I have installed ([go-swagger](https://goswagger.io/install.html#installing-from-source)) using docker with version :

```
version: v0.30.4
commit: df6da9b77aa9751f06bedb17fcf92b1ab67a7a47
```

and use following command to run the docker

```
alias swagger='docker run --rm -it  --user $(id -u):$(id -g) -e GOCACHE=/tmp -e GOPATH=$(go env GOPATH):/go -v $HOME:$HOME -w $(pwd) quay.io/goswagger/swagger'
```

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: You're running this command within the Container? If so, make sure you have a [volume mapping](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) defined which allows the container to access your filesystem if the `swagger.yaml` file is on your host system or copy the `swagger.yaml` to the correct location within your container.

Comment: I already edit the question, please have take a look, I think I already add volume mapping while running the docker.